# Android Intent is not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have just started with developing apps in android, but when I am trying to create an  email intent I am getting an error. The file crashes when the buttoon is clicked. The code is as follows:
MainActivity.java:-

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    Button myButton;
    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        private void onClick () {
            submit();
        }
    }

    );

    public void submit() {

        // Getting text from the EditText View
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        // Creating an email intent


        Intent email = new Intent(Intent ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, newString[]{"youremail@gmail.com"});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text);
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:hint="Name"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:onClick="submit"
        android:id="@+id/enter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try removing `if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {`

Comment: post the logcat. also i see that in your xml you use `Submit` while youre method name in java is `submit`. remember  "Submit" and "submit" are different from each other.

Comment: Dude in button's `xml` you write `Submit` and in the java you written `submit()`  how can you suppose it will work.

Comment: I posted the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the line:

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
```

Also, I believe that `Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` takes a string array. Instead, try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"xyz@gmail.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what **mattfred** has answered is correct. Do as he told. And then also if that not work then remove

```
onClick:"Submit"
```

from your **Button** attribute.

Give your button a specfic id and initialize **Button** in your activity.

```
Button myButton;
```

Then activity's onCreate

```
myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
private void onClick(){
submit();
}
});
```

I think I have found a bug.

Replace your **submit** method as I have done

```
    public void submit(){ 

    // Getting text from the EditText View
     EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
     String text = editText.getText().toString(); 
    // Creating an email intent


    Intent email =new Intent(Intent ACTION_SEND);   
email.setType("text/plain");
     email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"youremail@gmail.com"});
      email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,"Choose an Email client :"));
```

What you were doing wrong is you were getting text from a **TextView**. You have to get it from an **EditText**

Moreover, in your **submit** method you have initialized **TextView** with ID **R.id.name**. But there is no **TextView** in your xml and in your xml, your EditText is initialized with ID **R.id.name**.

More bug is found...

In your xml's **Button** attribute you have written

```
android:onClick="Submit"
```

But your method name is

`submit()` not `Submit()`

Remember, Java is case sensitive...

Also see, I think you can simply use

```
public void submit(){}
```

You have no reason to use

```
public void submit(View v){}
```

After all, change every code as I have told. Not only the method. You also remove

```
android:onClick="submit"
```

also from your XML's button attribute.

**Hope you have understood**

**--Sorry for my mistyped code. Actually now I am on Mobile device**

Comment: The code error after adding setOnClickListener while running the app.

Comment: After editind the code still the app crashes when Submit button is clicked

Comment: Can you please add the new written code in your question?

Comment: Please see my full answer. I have edited a lot. I believe if you do this then there should have no error

Comment: When i add setOnClickListener it is shown in red color. And when I run the app it fails to run.

Comment: Can you add your new written whole code to your question? Then I could understand your new bug. And see my full code. There is no error now. The code should work now perfectly